# Cofactor reflection maps greatest proper divisor to least (prime) proper divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, divisibility

Suppose that $y$ is a positive integer, and $z$ is the largest factor of $y$ such that $z<y$, then let $x=y/z$. Prove that $x$ must be a prime number.

Is there a simple way to solve this? It should be obvious but it's stumping me :/

Comment: Hint: suppose $x$ is not prime, so $x = ab$ for some $a,b > 1 $. Then think about $z' = az$

Comment: @JC574: Your simple comment is better than any of the answers posted!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ cofactor reflection $\, x \mapsto n/x\,$ is *order-reversing* on the set of nontrivial factors of $\,n,\,$ therefore it maps a maximal nontrivial factor to a minimal nontrivial factor (necessarily prime, else it would have a smaller  factor, contra minimality).

**Remark** $ $ Extended to *common divisors* [this method yields](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1318902/242) $\,{\rm lcm}(a,b) = ab/\gcd(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** If $d |x$ then $dz |y$ and $z \leq dz \leq y$. What can $dz$ be?

Answer (score 0):

Let $z$ be the largest factor of $y$ satisfying $y<z$. Suppose $y=xz$ where $x$ is not a prime integer. Then write $x=ab$; $1<a,b <x$; $a,b$ positive integers. But then $az$ also divides $z$ and satisfies $z<az<y$.